# Library to connect Rstudio to MemSQL Database

Tags: r, rstudio, singlestore

Is the library needed to connect to a MemSQL database the same as the one used for MySQL?

Would the library(RMySQL) work to establish this connection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general you can connect to MemSQL using the same client libraries as for MySQL. Try it out and ask if you run into any problems.

Nothing directly about Rstudio, but there are many examples of how to connect to MemSQL with various clients at https://docs.memsql.com/tutorials/v6.0/how-to-connect-to-memsql.